# Xamarin.iOS cannot register with Azure Notification Hub in iOS 13.1.2

Tags: azure, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

I have been dealing with this issue for a few days now.

Yesterday an update was released for the **Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.iOS NuGet** package.

The way to register for the notification hub is **NOW** different in the sample on the Github link for the nuget package than in the Microsoft Azure documentation.

I narrowed down the problem I believe to getting the right connection string. 
The Error occurs at this line:  **var hub = new SBNotificationHub(connectionString,HubName);**

------Documentation way of registering with hub("old" way, works only for iOS 12 for me):

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
{
    Hub = new SBNotificationHub(Constants.ListenConnectionString, Constants.NotificationHubName);

    Hub.UnregisterAllAsync (deviceToken, (error) => {
        if (error != null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error calling Unregister: {0}", error.ToString());
            return;
        }

        NSSet tags = null; // create tags if you want
        Hub.RegisterNativeAsync(deviceToken, tags, (errorCallback) => {
            if (errorCallback != null)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("RegisterNativeAsync error: " + errorCallback.ToString());
        });
    });
}
```

------Github sample code updated yesterday for the Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.iOS nuget package:

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications (UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
        {
            // Connection string from your azure dashboard
            var cs = SBConnectionString.CreateListenAccess(
                new NSUrl("sb://" + HUB_NAME + "-ns.servicebus.windows.net/"),
                HUB_LISTEN_SECRET);

            // Register our info with Azure
            var hub = new SBNotificationHub (cs, HUB_NAME);
            hub.RegisterNative (deviceToken, null, err => {

                if (err != null) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + err.Description);
                    homeViewController.RegisteredForNotifications ("Error: " + err.Description);
                } else  {
                    Console.WriteLine("Success");
                    homeViewController.RegisteredForNotifications ("Successfully registered for notifications");
                }
            });
        }
```

OR same code from different azure documenation also updated 13 hours ago as of now:

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications (UIApplication app, NSData deviceToken)
{
    // Connection string from your azure dashboard
    var cs = SBConnectionString.CreateListenAccess(
        new NSUrl("sb://yourservicebus-ns.servicebus.windows.net/"),
        "YOUR-KEY");

    // Register our info with Azure
    var hub = new SBNotificationHub (cs, "your-hub-name");
    hub.RegisterNativeAsync (deviceToken, null, err => {
        if (err != null)
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + err.Description);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
    });
}
```

I cannot seem to create the connection string properly.
On Azure Portal the connection string looks like this in the Notification Hub Access policies tab:

```
Endpoint=sb://namespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=ListenSharedPolicyName;SharedAccessKey=AccessKey
```

How to create the connection string properly please? Which is the servicebus part, which is the key(or the secret) part exactly, why is there the "-ns" part.

Best attempt so far was creating the connection string like this:

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(
            UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
        {

            try
            {
                var cs = SBConnectionString.CreateListenAccess(
                new NSUrl("sb://" + AppConstants.HUBNAME + "-ns.servicebus.windows.net/"),
                AppConstants.AccessKey);

                var hub = new SBNotificationHub(cs, AppConstants.DEV3_HUBNAME);

                // await hub.UnregisterAllAsync(deviceToken);

                hub.RegisterNative(deviceToken, null, err => {

                    if (err != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + err.Description);
                        //homeViewController.RegisteredForNotifications("Error: " + err.Description);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Success");
                        //homeViewController.RegisteredForNotifications("Successfully registered for notifications");
                    }
                });
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
```

But I one time got this error:

> Could not initialize an instance of the type 'Foundation.NSUrl': the
>   native 'initWithString:' method returned nil. It is possible to ignore
>   this condition by setting ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to
>   false.

And most of the times this:

> =================================================================     Native Crash Reporting
>   ================================================================= Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal
>   error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries  used by your
>
> ## application.
>
> =================================================================     Native stacktrace:
>   =================================================================     0x10473c190 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : (null)  0x104732a00 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : (null)  0x10473fc54 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : mono_pmip   0x197a47894 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib :
>       0x10299027c -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : (null)  0x1029903c4 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : (null)  0x102997b70 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : (null)  0x102998154 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : (null)  0x1029980cc -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : (null)  0x102995e74 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : (null)  0x102993aec -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : (null)  0x102992824 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : (null)  0x104714530 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : (null)  0x104702694 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : (null)  0x1029da3ac -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : (null)  0x102d59af4 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : (null)  0x104742fb4 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : mono_pmip   0x1047dc688 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : mono_pmip   0x1047dfb40 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : mono_pmip   0x10299ce1c -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : (null)  0x10299cb14 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : (null)  0x19bd632f8 -
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>       0x197a05610 - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib :
>       0x197a06184 - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib :
>       0x1979e935c - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib :
>       0x197cb63c4 -
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation :
>       0x197cb13b8 -
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation :
>       0x197cb08bc -
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation :
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific  0x1a1b1c328 -
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
>   : GSEventRunModal     0x102d59af4 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : (null)  0x104742fb4 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : mono_pmip   0x1047dc688 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : mono_pmip   0x1047e1834 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : mono_pmip   0x104727df0 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : (null)  0x10488da04 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : _Z9__isctypeim  0x1029d8f34 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : (null)  0x197b3b460 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib :
>
> =================================================================     Basic Fault Address Reporting
>   ================================================================= Memory around native instruction pointer (0x197a46f44): 0x197a46f34 
>   c0 03 5f d6 1f 20 03      0x19bd466d4 -
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>   UIApplicationMain     0x103683020 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : (null)  0x1035dbc7c -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : (null)  0x1035dbc04 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : (null)  0x1029d9064 -
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3DE84EC0-A042-42E6-8301-B233D104676A/MyAppName.iOS.app/MyAppName.iOS
>   : (null) d5 1f 20 03  d5 01 ec 7c 92  .._.. . .. ....|. 0x197a46f44 
>   20 00 c0 3d c3 f9 ff 10 62  04 c1 3c 02 0c 40 92   ..
>   =....b. .<.. @. 0x197a46f54  63 00 02 cb 61 00 c0 3d 00  1c a1 4e 05 00 00 14   c...a..= ...N.... 0x197a46f64  1f  20 03 d5 1f 20 03 d5 1f
>   20 03 d5 20 0c c1 3c   . ... ... .. . .<
>
> =================================================================     Managed Stacktrace:
>   =================================================================       at  <0xffffffff>       at
>   ApiDefinition.Messaging:void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr_IntPtr
>   <0x00007>       at
>   WindowsAzure.Messaging.SBNotificationHub:RegisterNative <0x00333>
>   at MyAppName.iOS.AppDelegate:RegisteredForRemoteNotifications
>   <0x002db>       at System.Object:runtime_invoke_dynamic <0x00103>       at
>    <0xffffffff>      at UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain
>   <0x00007>       at UIKit.UIApplication:Main <0x0002b>       at
>   UIKit.UIApplication:Main <0x00043>      at
>   MyAppName.iOS.Application:Main <0x000a3>    at
>
> ## System.Object:runtime_invoke_dynamic <0x00103>

Comment: Three things, First-Could you change your log reporting to verbose and see if you get anything else, and Second-That error is basically saying that there's something wrong with one of these NSURL intialization lines: `new NSUrl("sb://yourservicebus-ns.servicebus.windows.net/")`. Could you play around with the value in those? Third-Could you try to place an Exception Catchpoint or step through it to see what exception is thrown? Maybe trying using a try-catch?

Comment: @Saamer there are similar reports from other people that I have found online so I wonder if its an actual bug, not related to my device or code? Something maybe to do with Azure notification hubs and iOS 13 and XCode 11? I did play around with the values and I get same error. I also used a try catch, that SIGSEGV error occurs regardless of the try catch block at the point when registering with the hub.

Comment: There seems to be a solution posted on the issue you opened https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/39834 Have you tried that?

Comment: @Saamer I made this work, thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 2):

I made this work if anyone has the same issue, below is the working code. 
Works with NuGet package:

> Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.iOS v2.0.4

```
  try
     {
           AzureNotifHub = new SBNotificationHub(HUB_LISTENSHARED_CONNSTRING, HUBNAME);

          // update registration with Azure Notification Hub
           await AzureNotifHub.UnregisterAllAsync(deviceToken);


           var tags = new NSSet(AppConstants.IOSSUBSCRIPTIONTAGS.ToArray());
           await AzureNotifHub.RegisterNativeAsync(deviceToken, tags);

           var templateExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(120).ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
                    await AzureNotifHub.RegisterTemplateAsync(deviceToken, "defaultTemplate", AppConstants.IOS_APNS_TEMPLATE_BODY, templateExpiration, tags);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
           Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It was because of few white space inside the connectionString url. Removed and issue solved!!!